# How to disable paperclip file extension limits?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'd like to remove content type limitations for uploading files for my own needs. I did try this:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => ['/\Aimage\/.*\Z/', 'application/*']
```

but that doesn't work, what changes should I make to allow all file types to get uploaded?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be just the matter of removing this line completely. It is not necessary for paperclip to work.

UPDATE:

This however got changed in recent Paperclip version. Now you need to specify you don't want to validate content with:

```
do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :attachment
```

Comment: It is necessary, if I don't add this line, I get an error `Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError`